# Best Way To Save/Load Data To/From A .CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, numeric

I'm trying to save and load a list of tuples of 2 `ndarrays` and an `int` to and from a `.csv` file.

In my current implementation, when I save and load a list l, there is some error in the recovered list on the order of `10^-10`. Is there a way to save and recover values more precisely? I would also appreciate comments on my code in general. Thanks!

This is what I have now:

```
def save_l(l,path):
    tup=()
    for X in l:
        u=X[0].reshape(784*9)
        v=X[2]*np.ones(1)
        w=np.concatenate((u,X[1],v))
        tup+=(w,)
    L=np.row_stack(tup)
    df=pd.DataFrame(L)
    df.to_csv(path)

def load_l(path):
    df=pd.read_csv(path)
    L=df.values
    l=[]
    for v in L:
        tup=()
        for i in range(784):
            tup+=(v[9*i+1:9*(i+1)+1],)
        T=np.row_stack(tup)
        Q=v[9*784+1:10*784+1]
        i=v[7841]
        l.append((T,Q,i))
    return(l)
```

Comment: `csv` is a text file.  Float values will be rounded or clipped.  Don't use this format if you need to retain precision.  `ndarray` has `np.save` and `np.load` which will save the binary data, the bytes that are used in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the issue you are experiencing is due to absence of .csv file protection during save and load.

a good way to make sure that your file is locked until all data are saved/loaded completely is using a *context manager*. In this way, you won't lose any data in case your system stops execution due to whatever reason, because all results are saved in the moment when they are available.

I recommend to use the `with`-[statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), whose primary use is an exception-safe cleanup of the object used inside (in this case your .csv). In other words, with makes sure that files are closed, locks released, contexts restored etc.

```
with open("myfile.csv", "a") as reference:           # Drop to csv w/ context manager
     df.to_csv(reference, sep = ",", index = False)  # Same goes for read_csv
# As soon as you are here, reference is closed
```

If you try this and still see your error, it's not due to save/load issues.